# Do comments in NodeJs affect performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in the process of having to refactor an entire NodeJs project which is quite large. One of the biggest problems I'm facing is that my predecessor included literally *no* documentation.

I'm used to clientside js, where comments can be stripped via uglify (or similar) before deploying to a production environment.

Is there something similar for node, or how do people handle this? Is the performance impact of comments negligible?

Comment: Comments in server side language should not affect performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments do not affect code performance in a significant way. Neither in the in client nor in the server.

What happens in the client is that if you're including JavaScript with comments those lines are still being downloaded by the browser, without no extra benefit for the user.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not entirely correct, in V8(the javascript engine employed in Chrome, Opera aswell as nodejs) speed is indeed affected by comments as its heuristic for inlining functions checks the amount of characters of a function, [including comments](https://floitsch.blogspot.de/2012/03/optimizing-for-v8-inlining.html)(sadly this is still the case).
**However this should not affect OPs decision on using comments or not.**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I should've added the "in a non significant way" before.

Comment: Well significance depends on the use case, if you're doing real-time stuff like physics simulation this can be significant.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about that but I leave that to OP to point out, I don't think it was the case, but I'm happy to delete if the answer gets too much out of context ^^

Comment: No need to delete, just wanted to point out that there are cases where it *actually* makes a difference :)

Answer (score 0):

In client side code, comments add to the file size that needs to be sent to the browser, so that is why tools at used to remove comments. On the other hand, the comments in server side code doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Comments do not affect performance in a significant matter. How I understand it, the javascript program is being loaded into the memory. In this process the comments are being ignored and are not loaded into the memory. Meaning that only during the loading of your application you could experience extremely minor increase of loading time while having a lot of comments. But this is negligible.

Using uglify would not be necessary since users cannot read your NodeJS code. And it would make the newly refactored code less readable for you (which would be counterproductive).

Like Alberto and Konst are pointing out is that uglify can be used to reduce file size for downloading by the client.

Note: I do not know if i am exactly correct, please do correct me if i am wrong.